# How to Copy Files from one SP 2010 root Site to its sub Site (C#)

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, file, move

I manually created both "testFolder" under "http://test1/SitePages/" and "http://test1/sideA/SitePages/" using SP designer. There is a txt file in the folder "http://test1/SitePages/testFolder/", what Im trying to do is copy the txt file to subsite folder "http://test1/sideA/SitePages/testFolder"

```
protected void copyFile() 
            {
                SPSite mySite = new SPSite("http://test1/");
                SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb();
                SPFolder collFolder = myWeb.GetFolder("SitePages/testFolder");
                SPFileCollection collFiles = null;
                if (collFolder.Exists)
                {
                    collFiles = collFolder.Files;
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("Source folder dosenot exists");
                }

                myWeb.Dispose();
                mySite.Dispose();

                SPSite destSite = new SPSite("http://test1/sideA/");
                SPWeb destWeb = destSite.OpenWeb();
                SPFolder destFolder = destWeb.GetFolder("SitePages/testFolder");

                if (destFolder.Exists)
                {
                    foreach (SPFile oFile in collFiles)
                    {
                        oFile.CopyTo(destFolder + "/" + oFile.Name, true);
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    Response.Write("Target folder dosenot exists");
                }

                destWeb.Dispose();
                destSite.Dispose();

            }
```

0x81070925You cannot copy "/SitePages/testFolder/something.txt" to itself.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 0x81070925You cannot copy "/SitePages/testFolder/something.txt" to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the folder exists and that it is spelled correctly?  I've noticed a few spelling errors in your code and description of your code (Fodler, newFoler, etc.)  Could it be that simple?

Here is one thing you need to look out for when you are doing this:
http://sharepointlink.blogspot.com/2011/02/beware-of-spwebgetfolderurl.html

It seems that the GetFolder method won't necessarily tell you there is a problem right away.  You should check to be sure the folder/file exists before trying to copy it.

If this doesn't solve the issue, please include the full error message and where it occurs.  Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem.  I wasn't criticizing.  Instead I just wondered if it might be the root cause of your problem.  Did you figure that out?

Comment: Step through the code and watch your values.  I suspect the issue is the relative path to your folder.  Try putting the full path (URL) to it and see what happens.

Comment: Still the same error, cant copy file to itself

I changed both

SPFolder collFolder = myWeb.GetFolder("h*t*t*p://test1/SitePages/testFolder");

SPFolder destFolder = destWeb.GetFolder("h*t*t*p://test1/sideA/SitePages/testFolder");

Comment: This is a silly question, but are you sure that your sub-site doesn't use the same file system folder as the root site?  This isn't common (not even positive you can do it) but it sounds like the issue.

Comment: I created "SiteA" through SP designer, by click button "New Blank Web Site", and then specified the location :"h*t*t*p://test1/siteA"
     In SiteA, it contains following folder: _catalog, _private, m, SiteAssets, SitePages.         It seems sub-site using the same file system folder as the root site, but less folders, like the subset of root.